# Beginner help Netlogo, Output-print

Tags: excel, output, netlogo

I am an absolute beginner to this Netlogo software and have no programming experience whatsoever on it. I am using a sample program provided with the software to run a science experiment and I just want the raw data to use for a project but I do not know how to acquire it. I heard I need to use an output-print command but I am not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what raw data? For example, is there a plot of the particular data that you want? If so, edit the plot and you can see the name of the variable that is being plotted (let's say it is `count turtles`). Then, go to the code section and add the line `print-output count turtles` as a new line before the commend '`tick` in the `go` procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Dana, if you need to run multiple replicates I would check out [Behavior Space](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html). It is part of Netlogo (Tools -> Behavior Space) and allows you to easily save the output to a .csv file.

If you just want a quick and not-so-pretty data out, you could do something like:

```
to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks  
end

to go
  tick
  print-to-file 
end

to print-to-file

  file-open "example.csv"
  file-type (word ticks ",\n");; replace ticks with the variable you want out
  file-close

end
```

Which appends your output to the file "example.csv".

Comment: Thank you Luke! Excuse the silly question, but how do I identify my variable? I don't know what to type in... do I just type "population"? Or will I have to find the variable that is recognized?

Comment: Whenever I try to put in the code I get the following error message: "there is already a procedure called GO"

Comment: Dana, other than the predefined variables (like `color` for turtles) you have to create them yourself. It's hard to say without seeing your code and knowing what you're after, but you could try replacing 'ticks' with '(count turtles)'. As far as your second error- each procedure must have a unique name- there is already a `go` in your model, you need to add the contents of the one above to your existing procedure.

Comment: If there is any chance at all that you can help me with this program, I will be very grateful. Is there any way I can contact you.

Comment: Dana, I'm not sure about posting contact information on here. If you would like to edit your question to include more specific parts of your code, there is a chance I could help that way.